# Select falsey documents in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I have a Meteor collection where I want to specify a query to find all documents where an attribute is falsey.  In other words, where it does not exist, null, false.  In native Mongo the following syntax works:

```
find({category: "Cereal", showOnList: {"$ne": true}})
```

In this case, none of the documents have the element `showOnList` and therefore match my query.  In Meteor (client side) I get the following error when using this syntax:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:904:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:837:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate
(<anonymous>:693:21)InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM220:904InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM220:837InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM220:693
```

Anyone else run into this problem and have a workaround?  Is this a Meteor bug?

Comment: it might not be supported but the error says unexpected token ) maybe you have a type? If it's not a typo you will have to use `underscore` to iterate and find the ones you need create your own array on the client side

Comment: Thanks.  Pretty sure its not a type'o as I cut/paste from the mongo console directly to browser console.  I get this same error if I use the $or operator also.

Comment: I tried using the collection transform to add missing elements, but looks like that happens when pulling out of mini mongo.  Doesn't help with the find() query.  I need a Collection helper...

Comment: @MichelFloyd you're right I just did `Posts.find({_id: {$ne: "M6RgPgC4KbnvLxz8W"}}).fetch()` works perfectly

Comment: @MichelFloyd lol I did too because the error is a winner... It was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo some where here is a fully working query I just tested

`Posts.find({_id: {$ne: "M6RgPgC4KbnvLxz8W"}}).fetch()`

Comment: You're right.  Tried again in mongo, then again in Chrome...works.  Sorry for the false alarm!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could create this query with one statement. This is my workaround:

```
find({$or: [{ showOnList: null }, {showOnList: false}, {showOnList: {$exists: false}}] })
```